# Validate bootstrap modal fields on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap modal to get 'Start' and 'End' date for some course.

```
<div id="save_course_modal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal_header_class">
    <h4>Start Course</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <label class='selector_modal_label'>Course</label>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <p>Start date: <input type="text" id="start_date" size="30" /></p>
          </th>
          <th>
            <p>End date: <input type="text" id="end_date" size="30" /></p>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer modal_footer_class">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button id='add_course' class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Use Case:**

I want to validate two input fields with ids **'start_date'** and **'end_date'**.
Since, it is not a form and hence couldn't use 'required' attribute.

**I am thinking to use following:**

1. Remove **data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"** from
   button with **id='add_course'**.
2. Add **onclick='validate_course_fields();'** to above button.
3. If validations are fine then hide modal through **$('#save_course_modal').hide()**;

Any better solution is appreciated.

Comment: Is there something that you don't like about your solution?  Does it work?

Comment: Trevor: It works but it looks like some kind of hack done around bootstrap modal to do my work.

Comment: Your solution is legal :) when you add data-dismiss="modal" attribute anything in modal you say close modal when clicking this element.

Answer (score 0):

First it would be best to avoid using tables to align the elements in modal.

```
<div id="save_course_modal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal_header_class">
        <h4>Start Course</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label class='selector_modal_label'>Course</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2"> Start Date:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10>
                <input type="text" id="start_date" class="form-control" size="30" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2"> End Date:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10>
                <input type="text" id="end_date" class="form-control" size="30" />
            </div> 
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer modal_footer_class">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button id='add_course' class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

In your javascript code you should use the event hide of the Bootstrap that can be seen in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
$("#add_course").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //remove the default button action

    //validation
    if(validate_form()){
        //When validation is OK

        //hide modal using event of the Bootstrap
        $("#save_course_modal").modal("hide");
    }
})
```